# How can I make the Apple Music fonts smaller in iOS 10?

Tags: font, apple-music, ios

I have a perfect eye sight and can read tiny text, too. The Apple Music revamp in iOS 10 has huge text which is very awkward for me and difficult to use. I searched for any setting, but could not find one. Is there any possibility of reducing the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to modify the display in Apple Music.